# How can handle in better way the handler message from service to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, android-handler

For communicate from started service to fragment I did in this way :

**In the service body**

```
    Handler handler;


public synchronized void setHandler(Handler h)
{
    handler = h;
}

protected synchronized void sendMessage(int arg1)
{
    Message m = handler.obtainMessage();
    m.arg1=arg1;
    handler.sendMessage(m);
}
```

In the fragment :

```
@Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = ("service_name") binder.getService();
        mService.setHandler(serviceHandler);


    }
```

and :

```
private Handler serviceHandler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper()) 
    {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
            {
                someF(msg);
            }
    };

    private void someF(Message msg)
        {
            //some functions
        }
```

In onDestroy I have did in this way :

Now in fragment's ondestroy I do this :

```
if (mIsBound) {
                // Detach our existing connection.
                App.getAppContext().unbindService(mConnection);
                mIsBound = false;
            }
```

Function to bind and unbind from the service :

```
void doBindService() {

    Appbike.getAppContext().bindService(new Intent(getActivity(), Bike_ble_service.class), mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;

}

/**
 * Detach our existing connection
 */
void doUnbindService() {
    if (mIsBound) {
        Appbike.getAppContext().unbindService(mConnection);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}
```

**edit2** : Now In the service I used

```
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }
 @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }
```

And in fragment I can call service function through the binder.

How can resolve my problem ? If I do unbindservice the message from the service continue to arrives ..

Do I have to change everything ?

**SOLUTION** : I try to do this in the service :

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    iHaveToSendMsg = true;
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
    {
        iHaveToSendMsg = false;
        return true;
    }
```

and in sendmessage I check the flag, if it is false I don't send message. Is a possible workaround ?

**MY SOLUTION'S PROBLEM** : "*In my solution there is one problem... Onbind isn't called everytime that I do a bindService :/ What can I do ?
I can't rewrite all the code and use callback, for this time I have to use handler message.. :(* "

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION** : can I set the flag in setHandler() function

```
public synchronized void setHandler(Handler h)
    {
        iHaveToSendMsg = true;
        handler = h;
    }
```

Comment: unregister your client in onStop or onPause and register it in onStart/onResume

Comment: @pskink Thanks to the answer :) Now in ondestroy I do this : if (mIsBound) { // Detach our existing connection. App.getAppContext().unbindService(mConnection); mIsBound = false; } But the problem is still there, and gives me this error if the activity is been force closed .. "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed"
 Maybe I have to change somethinf in the sethandler ?

How can unregister this ? 
public Messenger (Handler target)

Comment: why do you use Messages at all? you have local bound service, right? so use "local bound service" pattern

Comment: @pskink I have a started service, And I bind the fragment to the started service to call service's function.
In this case then is better to use this : public Messenger (IBinder target) ?

Comment: no, no Messenger, see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder

Comment: I edited the first post. I have some doubt on the messenger + started service function :/

Comment: why Messenger? is your Service a remote one? is it run in the another process?

Comment: Do you not suggest to me to use messenger ? i misunderstood...

Comment: see above: "no, no Messenger,", just use local bound service pattern

Comment: Ah ok. I'm confused. I have used binder to call service function from the fragment.

And now I have to send message from service to activity. For do that I use sethandler ecc ecc, I did in wrong way ?

Comment: then just use a simple callback

Comment: Then I have wrong to use     


public synchronized void setHandler(Handler h)
{
    handler = h;
}
 and 

protected synchronized void sendMessage(int arg1)
{
    Message m = handler.obtainMessage();
    m.arg1=arg1;
    handler.sendMessage(m);
}

:( I have to change everything... damn :(
*
Thanks for the help !

Comment: I edit the first post :) Thanks to everything and sorry if I bother you :/

Comment: @pskink In my solution there is one problem... Onbind isn't called everytime that I do a bindService :/ What can I do ?
I can't rewrite all the code and use callback, for this time I have to use handler message.. :(

Comment: why do you want it to be called each time the client binds?

Comment: Hi ! 
Because If I stop a fragment then I reopen fragment I want to set flag iHaveToSendMsg = true;
and i want that sendmessage checks this flag to know I it should sendmessage or not.

In the first post I add more detail on my wrong solution

Comment: see my first comment: "unregister your client in onStop or onPause and register it in onStart/onResume ", see how its dont via aidl https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/apps/ApiDemos/bin/aidl/com/example/android/apis/app/IRemoteService.aidl?spec=svn.mobile.4f1b0beaf10cc1e627c72c38700fe235f6366249&repo=mobile&r=4f1b0beaf10cc1e627c72c38700fe235f6366249

Comment: actually I do in this way.
I register my client in onStart with doBindService:
And I unregister it in onStop with 
doUnbindService();

And I call setHandler() in onServiceConnected

And I set the flag when I call setHandler and set the flag to false when I call onunbind

Comment: so what is the problem? set your flag on in doBindService and off in doUnbindService

Comment: Thanks ! :)
Can ask you other thing ? Why a callback is better  than handler message ?

Comment: because it is a direct call, no need for Messages in local bound service

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I start to change my code to callback, last thing : when we have to prefer messages to callback ?  
Sorry for the too many qeustions .